WPF - Cannot highlight part of the text after applying customized template on ComboBox
First of all, I created a ComboBox and set up everything without any styles. Then I wanted to change a foreground, but found out it cannot be done directly in properties since Windows 8. I generated a template and changed colors. More changes had to be made, like allowing text input etc. But now everywhere I click on the combobox, it drops down the list instead of removing highlight from the text. I can still edit the ComboBox's Textbox, but cannot highlight part of it. I assume there's a problem in ComboBox template, but couldn't find it even when I removed most parts that aren't linked to colors. What am I missing?
Note: background image is a solid color #2e3b4c
Simplified UserControl XAML
<UserControl x:Class="EntryMaster.View.BAdRa"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:EntryMaster.ViewModel"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="750" d:DesignWidth="900"
         Style="{StaticResource Page_Style}">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:BAdRaVM/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid Margin="15">
    <Border CornerRadius="0, 20, 20, 0"/>
    <Image Source="/Image/bg3.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
    <ComboBox Template="{DynamicResource ComboStyleRe}" Text="Choose any product" Style="{StaticResource ComboStyle}" IsHitTestVisible="True" x:Name="chooseProduct" Margin="0,140,0,0" Width="750" IsTextSearchEnabled="False" 
         Loaded="ChProduct_Loaded" PreviewKeyUp="ChProduct_PrevKeyUp" SelectionChanged="ChProduct_SelectionChanged" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" Height="30" IsEditable="True">
</Grid>

Simplified Style XAML

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Background" Color="#FF47566B"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Border" Color="#FFACACAC"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Glyph" Color="#FFDBDBDB"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Text" Color="Transparent"/> 
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Background" Color="Transparent"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Border" Color="#FFACACAC"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Background" Color="Transparent"/> <!--#6c7889-->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Border" Color="Transparent"/>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FF47566B"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Glyph" Color="#FFDBDBDB"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Background" Color="Transparent"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Background" Color="Transparent"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Background" Color="#FF47566B"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Glyph" Color="#FFDBDBDB"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Background" Color="Transparent"/> <!--was #FF47566B, has to be set to transparent to prevent flashing-->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Background" Color="Transparent"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Border" Color="#6c7889"/>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Background" Color="#7E8fa3"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFACACAC"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Glyph" Color="#FFBFBFBF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Background" Color="#FF47566B"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Border" Color="#FFACACAC"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Background" Color="Transparent"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Border" Color="Transparent"/>

<Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border x:Name="templateRoot" Background="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Background}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Border}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Border x:Name="splitBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                        <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="F1 M 0,0 L 2.667,2.66665 L 5.3334,0 L 5.3334,-1.78168 L 2.6667,0.88501 L0,-1.78168 L0,0 Z" Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Value="false"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Value="false"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Border}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Border}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Border}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Border}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Value="false"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Border}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Value="false"/>
                            <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Border}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboStyleRe" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" 
                 Style="{x:Null}" 
                 Template="{DynamicResource ComboBoxTextBox}" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                 VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                 Background="Transparent" 
                 IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" 
                 Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                 Visibility="Hidden"
                 Focusable="True"
                 IsHitTestVisible="True"
                 Foreground="#FFDBDBDB"
                 CaretBrush="#FFDBDBDB"
                 BorderThickness="0"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                 VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                 Text="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" 
               AllowsTransparency="true" 
               Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
               IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" 
               Margin="1" 
               Placement="Bottom" 
               PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}">
            <theme:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="shadow" 
                                          Color="Transparent" 
                                          MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=templateRoot}" 
                                          MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                <Border x:Name="dropDownBorder" 
                        Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" 
                        BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" 
                        BorderThickness="1">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                        <Grid x:Name="grid" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                            <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="opaqueRect" 
                                           Fill="#FF47566B" 
                                           Opacity="30" 
                                           Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" 
                                           Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=dropDownBorder}"/>
                            </Canvas>
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" 
                                            KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" 
                                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </theme:SystemDropShadowChrome>
        </Popup>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" 
                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                      IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" 
                      Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                      ClickMode="Press" 
                      Focusable="False"/>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" 
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" 
                          Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" 
                          ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                          IsHitTestVisible="False" 
                          Focusable="False" 
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Setter TargetName="contentPresenter" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="shadow" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
            <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="shadow" Value="#71000000"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="dropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
        </Trigger>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="true"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>

